# What is the term that describes the image that is seen when something is moving fast?

Tags: word-choice

For example, when you move your hand back and forth quickly (or just any object), you see "two" in a way. When something quick is thrown, there's a line that is left behind that follows that object.

I suppose "afterimages" suits it the closest, but it doesn't seem to be the right term.

For the second example, I think "trail" works, but I don't think it works for the first example.

Is there any specific terms, or could it only be described?

Comment: A "blur", perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term used in animation is motion blur.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "Persistence of vision", except that's mostly used for when the object is glowing - like those LED sticks that you wave and it makes text in mid-air.